# How to run two FOR loops at the same time

Tags: java, android

I´m working with accelerometer and the first code is Shake detector:
(Code1)

```
if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //**********************************************************************
        if ((now - mLastForce) > SHAKE_TIMEOUT) {
              mShakeCount = 0;
            }

            if ((now - mLastTime) > TIME_THRESHOLD) {
              long diff = now - mLastTime;
              float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - mLastX - mLastY - mLastZ) / diff * 10000;
              if (speed > FORCE_THRESHOLD) {
                if ((++mShakeCount >= SHAKE_COUNT) && (now - mLastShake > SHAKE_DURATION)) {
                  mLastShake = now;
                  mShakeCount = 0;
                  if (mShakeListener != null) { 
                    mShakeListener.onShake(); 
                  }
                }
                mLastForce = now;
              }
              mLastTime = now;
              mLastX = x;
              mLastY = y;


              mLastZ = z;
```

With this i get message, when tho phone is shaked:
(Code2)

```
  mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new OnShakeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShake() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shake!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I have also  for loop for saving accelerometer values x,y,z into array every 2 secons:
(Code3)

```
 if (lastUpdate == -1 || (curTime - lastUpdate) > 2000) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            x = values[0];
            y = values[1];
            z = values[2];

                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                    if (column == 0) {
                        p[row][column] = values[0];

                    }
                    if (column == 1) {
                        p[row][column] = values[1];
                        //yacc.setText("Os X: " + p[row][column]);
                    }
                    if (column == 2) {
                        p[row][column] = values[2];
                        //zacc.setText("Os X: " + p[row][column]);
                    }}
                    if (row == 0) {
                        xacc.setText("Os X: " + p[row][0] + " " + p[row][1] +" " + p[row][2]);
                    }
                    if (row == 1) {
                        yacc.setText("Os X: " + p[row][0] + " " + p[row][1] +" " + p[row][2]);
                    }
                    if (row == 2) {
                        zacc.setText("Os X: " + p[row][0] + " " + p[row][1] +" " + p[row][2]);
                    }
                    if (row == 3) {
                        z2acc.setText("Os X: " + p[row][0] + " " + p[row][1] +" " + p[row][2]);
                    }
                    if (row == 4) {
                        z3acc.setText("Os X: " + p[row][0] + " " + p[row][1] +" " + p[row][2]);
                    }
                    row++;
                if (row == 5) {
                    row = 0;
                }
```

Code3 is never ending and code1 is shake detector. How can i run it together, maybe with threads (how) or anything else?

Comment: if you want to run two loops ( or more ) at the same time , use Threads . just define each loop in one thread, and then start your threads :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you want to run two loops ( or more ) at the same time , use `Threads` . just define each loop in one thread, and then start your threads :)

**Example :**

First thread :

```
public class ThreadForLoopA extends Thread{
  // variables for your Thread ... 
   @Override
   public void run(){
      // your first loop here ...
   }
}
```

Second thread :

```
public class ThreadForLoopB extends Thread{
  // variables for your Thread ... 
   @Override
   public void run(){
      // your second loop here ...
   }
}
```

Start all your threads like this :

```
ThreadForLoopA threadA = new ThreadForLoopA();
ThreadForLoopB threadB = new ThreadForLoopB();

//start threads (the two loops will be executed at the same time)
threadA.start();
threadB.start();
```

Comment: @Override
 public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
  x = values[0];
  y = values[1];
  z = values[2];

Comment: How can i get accelerometer values from onSensorChanged to ThreatForLoopA?

Comment: pass them into the constructor as parameters.