# Have 2 processes running side by side. Homework

Tags: java, stack, queue

As stated in the title, this is for homework and I'm not looking for specific code, just ideas on how to implement this.

I need to make a simulation of elevators in a building.

So I have an array of elevators and my program randomly generates requests for these elevators to go from 1 random floor to another. When a request is received the elevator goes from its current location to pick up the passenger and drop them off to their destination. Moving each floor takes up 1 unit of time.

I want to simulate how having more or less elevators affects the number of passengers that can be served in a given amount of time.

I generate requests by:

```
while (!arrayOfRequests.isEmpty()){
sourceFloor = arrayOfRequets[0].getSource();
destinationFloor = arrayOfRequets[0].getDestination();

elevatorMovement(sourceFloor, destinationFloor);

remove(arrayOfRequests[0]);
}
```

Now the elevatorMovement method goes and does its thing and once it is done, I remove that request from the stack.

The problem is I need my program to take care of the next request and give it to elevator # 2 while elevator #1 is busy handling the previous request.

How can this be achieved? This class is too basic to require advanced concepts like threading etc.
Oh and this is all in Java.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I know you aren't asking for code, but this site is also not the place to ask for help in designing your code. There are other sites online that can help w/this

Comment: Also, I think threading would be the way I would take that. It would be a good app to learn how to thread and since it is simple, threading would be as well

Comment: Could you please guide me to the right resource.

Comment: http://www.codingforums.com/ google is a friend

Comment: Are multiple people allowed on the elevator?

Comment: Nope. One person at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way I know to run 2 loops at the same time would be to thread. Check out [How to run two FOR loops at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360099/how-to-run-two-for-loops-at-the-same-time) if you want to thread it.
The other way I would use is to not run each at the same time, just one after each other. To do that, you may want to use an if/elif sequence where you run each loop after the other. Alternately, you could randomize the array chosen and choose `arrayOfRequests`/`arrayOfRequests2`(the second elevator) randomly, accounting that you have an if condition that checks if the elevator is in motion or not.
I suggest to speak to your teacher about threading. If he says no, randomize it (It will even help make it look like a real elevator!). If he says yes, then you can thread it (And achieve your goal).

Comment: Thank you. You might be right. I think I may have misunderstood the assignment as well. I'll talk to my professor about this.

Comment: I hope it helps!